# Sinatra with existing database (that doesn't abide by naming conventions)

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, firebird, datamapper

I have an existing legacy Firebird database with nonstandard table and field names.

I would like to write a Sinatra app that can access it and display information.   I've seen stuff like dm-is-reflective that appears to work when a database has proper naming conventions, but how do I use DataMapper (or ActiveRecord whichever is the easiest) to access those tables?

For example, assuming I had these two tables:

```
Bookshelfs
    shelf_id: integer
    level: integer
    created: timestamp

Book
    id: integer
    id_of_shelf: integer
    title: string
    pages: integer
```

Something like with odd naming conventions that don't follow any set pattern and where one table's record might "own" multiple entries in another table even though there is not foreign_key assigned.

How would you set up datamapper (or activerecord) to communicate with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in to this gem to get setup with ActiveRecord on Sinatra:
https://github.com/bmizerany/sinatra-activerecord

As for how to define the relations, activerecord can do this easily.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bookshelf, :class_name => 'Bookshelf', :foreign_key => 'id_of_shelf'
end

class Bookshelf < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, :class_name => 'Book', :foreign_key => 'id_of_shelf'
end
```

Comment: Does that only work with postgress, sqlite3 or myssql? I need to work with Firebird.

Comment: The point of activerecord is to be relational database independent.  So as long as whatever database you want to use is a relational database it probably works with ActiveRecord.  Just looked and it looks like firebird is supported: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/FirebirdAdapter

Comment: You need to use the active record Firebird adaptor

Comment: After firebird installation you need to type gem install activerecord-fb-adapter I have created a simple guide on how you need to install it http://mapopa.blogspot.ro/2009/02/installing-firebird-active-record-for.html

Comment: Thanks I finally got this working.  However there do appear to be issues with Fb gem on mac or something on my mac is not installed correctly.  I have it working on Windows though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you figured out how to connect to your legacy database using ActiveRecord's Firebird adapter, the next thing I would do is define a view on top of each table, e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW books AS SELECT * FROM Book;
CREATE VIEW bookshelves AS SELECT * FROM Bookshelfs;
```

This way you can simply define models Book and Bookshelf in ActiveRecord as per usual and it will find everything in the right place inside the database.